# Undestand the name of the block to rewrite

Tags: magento-1.9, product, blocks, magento-community

Using Magento, I'd like to add a new column in the Product details, inside the tab "Related Products" and "Up-sells" (Catalogue > Manage Products > *Select a Product* > **Related Products**).

How can I find the right name of the block to extend or rewrite?

(Magento CE 1.9)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to add a column in related product grid within product edit page.

You will need to extend these class

1. For related `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Related`
2. For upsell `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Upsell`

Also look all other tabs inside `Tab` folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sounds great, how did you find/generate the two block names?

Comment: You can always check these classes in magento core folders. app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Related.php

Comment: Did this help you?

Answer (score 1):

As a general advice to find out template path and block class I suggest you enable the hints

For frontend it is an out of box feature under system > configuration > developer. Switch the scope to the store you want and enable the hints.

For backend, I suggest you follow this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373481/enable-template-path-hint-in-admin-pages-magento or use the awesome Alan Storm's extension CommerceBug